# Showing button based on data value

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, jstl

I am having a jsp page on which am trying to show a button depending on my variable flag.

If flag=0 then i want to have a submit ADD button but if flag is set to 1 then i want to have a disabled REQUEST SEND button and other button should not be shown while other is been shown.

Here is my jsp code part :

```
<%
   String groupidd = request.getSession().getAttribute("groupid").toString();
   s=null;
   rs=null;
   int flag=0;
   String sql="select * from TBGROUPUSERS where I_ID=? and GU_GROUPID=?";

    s = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    s.setString(1,idperson);
    s.setString(2,groupidd);
    rs=s.executeQuery();
    if(rs.next())
    flag=1;
   %>
```

Now based on this flag value how i can do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the flag to request after the if block -

```
request.setAttribute("flag", flag);
```

And later use the `<c:choose>` for conditional display -

```jsp
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${requestScope.flag == 1}">
        <!-- flag is 1 -->
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <!-- flag isn't 1 -->
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

---

**Note: Scriplets in JSP is a bad practice. I strongly recommend that you read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3180202/738746).**

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have a button like this in your html

///input type='submit' value='button' id='b1'///

in java script do some thing like this.

```
if(<%=flag == 0%>)
{
 document.getElementById('b1').value="add"
}
```

Comment: i didnt get ur answer

Comment: neither do i get your question. I can help you if you can share a bit more of your code.